# Am I Correctly Adding An Object To Core Data?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I have an entity "Routine" with a to many relationship to "Exercise" called "routineExercises".

I have a method called `addExercise` which should add an Exercise to an instance of Routine.

Is this the correct way to implement this in code?

```
Exercise *exercise = (Exercise *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Exercise" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

exercise.name = selectedExercise;

NSMutableSet *exercises = [[NSMutableSet alloc]init];

[exercises addObject:exercise];

Routine *routine = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Routine" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

routine.routineExercises = exercises;
```

Update: I am getting an error at routine.routineExercises = exercises that says "-[Routine setRoutineExercises:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x711bf30
2011-04-27 01:25:37.683 Curl[888:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Routine setRoutineExercises:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x711bf30'
"

Update:

```
-(void)addExercise
{
   if (managedObjectContext == nil) 
    { 
        managedObjectContext = [(CurlAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext]; 
        [managedObjectContext retain];
    }

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Exercise" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:entity];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
    if (mutableFetchResults == nil) {
        // Handle the error.
    }

    Exercise *exercise = (Exercise *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Exercise" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    exercise.name = selectedExercise;

    NSMutableSet *exercises = [NSSet setWithObjects:exercise,nil];

    Routine *routine = (Routine *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Routine" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    routine.routineExercises = exercises;

    if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) 
    {
        // Handle the error.
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", error);

    [self.routineTableView reloadData];
    [mutableFetchResults release];
    [request release];
}
```

[image]

Error:

```
2011-04-27 03:05:58.902 Curl[1954:207] -[Routine setRoutineExercises:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5d4a4e0
2011-04-27 03:05:58.904 Curl[1954:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Routine setRoutineExercises:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5d4a4e0'
```

Routine.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class Exercise;

@interface Routine : NSManagedObject {
@private
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * timeStamp;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet* routineExercises;

@end
```

Routine.m

```
#import "Routine.h"
#import "Exercise.h"


@implementation Routine
@dynamic name;
@dynamic timeStamp;
@dynamic routineExercises;

- (void)addRoutineExercisesObject:(Exercise *)value {    
    NSSet *changedObjects = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:&value count:1];
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"routineExercises" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:changedObjects];
    [[self primitiveValueForKey:@"routineExercises"] addObject:value];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"routineExercises" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:changedObjects];
    [changedObjects release];
}

- (void)removeRoutineExercisesObject:(Exercise *)value {
    NSSet *changedObjects = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:&value count:1];
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"routineExercises" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation usingObjects:changedObjects];
    [[self primitiveValueForKey:@"routineExercises"] removeObject:value];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"routineExercises" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation usingObjects:changedObjects];
    [changedObjects release];
}

- (void)addRoutineExercises:(NSSet *)value {    
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"routineExercises" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:value];
    [[self primitiveValueForKey:@"routineExercises"] unionSet:value];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"routineExercises" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:value];
}

- (void)removeRoutineExercises:(NSSet *)value {
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"routineExercises" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation usingObjects:value];
    [[self primitiveValueForKey:@"routineExercises"] minusSet:value];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"routineExercises" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation usingObjects:value];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing the cast to Routine *.

Change

```
Routine *routine = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Routine" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
```

to

```
Routine *routine = (Routine *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Routine" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
```

Comment: Thanks!  I think I need to add a line something like `NSMutableSet *exercises = [exercise mutableSetValueForKey:@"name"];` ?

Comment: That will give you read write access to the unordered to-many relationship and will give you the relating/unrelating you need. You could also do `NSSet *exercises = [NSSet setWithObjects:exercise,nil];` and then keep your `routine.routineExercises = exercises;` the same. Is it not saving now?

Comment: I used the code you just added, but now i get error at `exercises addObject:exercise` that says  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFSet addObject:]: mutating method sent to immutable object' .  I think in the entity classes, the relationship is an NSSet rather than an NSMutableSet.

Comment: If you are using my code, you won't need to call `[exercises addObject:exercise];` since the exercise object is already added to the exercises NSSet on instantiation.

Comment: Ok, i fixed that, but i'm still getting the error " *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Routine setRoutineExercises:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5d4a4e0`" for line `routine.routineExercises = exercises`.

Comment: [Here's the CoreData reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdUsingMOs.html) scroll down to the **To-many relationships** section for more info.

Comment: Did you change the `Routine *routine = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Routine" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];` line to `Routine *routine = (Routine *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Routine" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];`?

Comment: yes I have changed that already.  Ill update the question with the updated code I am using.

Comment: Are you getting the same error as before? (Unrecognized selector...) Could you post the complete error?

Comment: What's the definition of Routine look like?

Comment: let me post in question. 1 sec.

Comment: Try to change `routine.routineExercises = exercises;` to `[routine addRoutineExercises:exercises];`

Comment: when i use that, it says "method addRoutineExercise not found

Comment: I have a table with a list of routines, each routine should have its own specific list of exercises, right now, whatever execise i add to a routine, shows up on all routines, instead of just that specific routine.

Comment: I notice on the code of your Routine.h file you have `@class Exercise;` instead of `@class Routine`. Was that a copy error or is that an error in the actual file?

Comment: thats how xcode did it, i think it is suppsoed to be like that because it is referencing the class Exercise.

Comment: Does error have to do with Routine class being NSSet and my code being NSMutableSet?

Comment: Got it working, I had to change the name of the data model. It was looking for the wrong one.  But it still is making the same list for all routines instead of one per routine.

Comment: I'm glad you got it working! You might want to put that in a separate question. I'm not sure how you need your relationships between sessions, exercises, and routines, but just looking at it you might want to go Session <-->> Routine <-->> Exercises <-->> Set. Some more info on how you are using it might help too, which would also be better in its own question.